# while loop not terminating curious

Tags: python, while-loop

```py
import math

x = 4

a = 1
while a<11:
    if a**3 < math.floor(x/1000):
        a+=1
```

why doesn't my code terminate? That is, why doesn't my code return the maximum value of a?

However if I add the if statement in the while loop then it works, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

for `a = 1` → `a ** 3 = 1`.
`math.floor(x/1000)` → `math.floor(4/1000) = 0`.

`if a**3 < math.floor(x/1000):` never becomes `True` and values of `a` does not increment. That's why `while-loop` not terminating.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code wouldn't terminate as the `if` condition is never satisfied, so the value of `a` doesn't increase.
The `if` condition is not satisfied as it is, for the first time (when a = 1):

```
a**3 < math.floor(x/1000):
```

which is same as:

```
1 < 0
```

which is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and evaluate this manually.

In `math.floor()`, the `x / 1000` evaluates to `4 / 1000`, which will all turn into 0 (since `math.floor` drops everything after the decimal point). On the other side, you have `a**3`, which is `1**3`, which is equal to `1`.

Therefore, the statement says `if 1 < 0:`, which is False, and therefore `a` does not increment. Since `a` does not change, the `while` condition will always stay False and will therefore keep iterating forever.